# 2.0.0: IllegalStateException: Cannot stream a request body without chunked encoding or a known content length

Tags: java, okhttp

OkHttp version: 2.0.0

I've received the following exception stack trace through Google Play:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot stream a request body without
>   chunked encoding or a known content length! at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.createRequestBody(HttpTransport.java:68)
>   at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:254)
>   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:198) at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$200(Call.java:36) at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:143) at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)

This is exactly how requests are made:

```
Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
requestBuilder.addHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
requestBuilder.addHeader("Accept", "application/hal+json");
requestBuilder.url(transformedURL);

RequestBody requestBody = body == null ? null : RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), gson.toJson(body));
requestBuilder.method(method, requestBody);

okHttpClient.newCall(requestBuilder.build()).enqueue(new com.squareup.okhttp.Callback() { ...
```

At first it seemed related to [this bug](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/745), but it's already been fixed. Also, we've tested POST requests with an empty body several times during development. 
This app only does GET and POST requests.

What could have possibly led to this error?

Comment: have you found the reason? I'm getting the same problem and still don't know the root cause as I have used the same code successfully before.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the HTTP request? If you can create a reproducible test case, please file a bug with OkHttp and we'll fix.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I've just added the request creation above.
I didn't manage to reproduce it yet. It was reported only once so far, 2 weeks after release and a few hundred users.

Comment: You shouldn't use a null body with POST. That should fix your crash. I'll try to get OkHttp to complain earlier!

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. This very same app have been making POST requests with empty bodies for weeks now, and is working just fine.

Also, I couldn't find this "a body is required for POST requests" rule on the HTTP RFC: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3

Comment: As I suspected, empty bodies on POST requests are valid, as suggested by the HTTP RFC section 3.3.2: `For example, a Content-Length header field is normally sent in a POST request even when the value is 0 (indicating an empty payload body)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant null specifically. Null is different from empty.

Comment: My bad, I thought you meant empty.
I'm still not confident the null body's the exception cause, as it worked just fine in every try so far. My desire is to understand and reproduce the error, but the stack trace didn't say anything about the request, which makes doing so difficult. I'll dig some more into this stack-related code.

Comment: I seem to get this error when the device can't connect to a proxy server.

Comment: @Liam-Cottle Our test team were checking some edge cases and we get this error only when they deliberately misconfigure the proxy

Comment: @JesseWilson: Can you please checkout the issue? It's still happening and can be resolved if I add the header. I have posted the answer, please let me know whether it is correct way or not. Thanks !!

Comment: Medul, please create an executable test case to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is being thrown from following piece of code:

**package okhttp3.internal.http;**

**Http1xStream.java**

```
  @Override public Sink createRequestBody(Request request, long contentLength) throws IOException {
    if ("chunked".equalsIgnoreCase(request.header("Transfer-Encoding"))) {
      // Stream a request body of unknown length.
      return newChunkedSink();
    }

    if (contentLength != -1) {
      // Stream a request body of a known length.
      return newFixedLengthSink(contentLength);
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException(
        "Cannot stream a request body without chunked encoding or a known content length!");
  }
```

And to solve this issue, I required to add one header to my request which can be added like this: `.addHeader("Transfer-Encoding","chunked")`:

OP's sample :

```
Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
requestBuilder.addHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
requestBuilder.addHeader("Accept", "application/hal+json");
```

**`requestBuilder..addHeader("Transfer-Encoding","chunked")`**

```
requestBuilder.url(transformedURL);
```